# [Ignite]Problem upgrading Ignite 2.7 Services to 2.10....Services always getting canceled?

Tags: spring, ignite

I completed the code upgrade and removed all deprecated calls from my service code.

This is a Java Spring application and all services come up (as reported in the log files) when the Cluster (of 5 nodes) starts up.

However, when I try to get a serviceProxy to each service, all services get cancelled as a result of ServiceDeploymentTask attempting to do a redeploy of the services!!  The redeploy fails and only cancels all of the services and fails to restart them.   This can be demonstrated with both a thick and a thin client.

Why is Ignite trying to redeploy the services? (and why don't the services restart?)

Is there something I'm missing from the move to Ignite 2.10???

Finally, why does a Java Thin Client create a NODE_JOIN event?

Thanks in advance.
Greg

Comment: Is it possible to share the logs? Java thin client won't trigger EVT_NODE_JOINED because a thin node can't be a part of the topology, something wrong is happening here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't scrub the logs and get them out.   But, that is what I thought (thin clients should not generate topology changes).  What would cause a redeploy to be called/queued, any idea?

Comment: @GregSylvain can you share a reproducer for your issue? Afaik thin client appearance should not emit NODE_JOIN event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Igniters, I found my issue with the thin client kicking off a NODE_JOIN host. (In my refactoring of a thick client, I left the Spring bean connection outside of the _if thin client_  block.)  Sorry for the erroneous scenario.